# Comparing results returned by query SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have written code for comparing user credentials in database. First I check the username and then based on the returned results, I compare the password. If both match, I open another activity. The code seems fine to me, but I have no experience in database stuff, I might be missing somehthing crucial here. The following code is not working for some reason.

```
public boolean Compare(String username, String pass)
{
    Cursor c = sqlDB.query(DB_NAME, columns, DB_COL_EMAIL + "='" + username+ "'", null, null, null, null);



    if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "inside check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        c.moveToFirst();

        int passwordCol_number= c.getColumnIndex(DB_COL_PASS);
        boolean found = false;

        while(c.moveToNext())

        {
            found = pass.equals(c.getString(passwordCol_number));

            if(found)
                return true;
        }
    }
 return false;
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: post the `logcat` trace that you get so that we can understand what is the error that you are encountering

Comment: Not answering your question here but you really really should read about SQL injections and password hashing ;) (and also java naming conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enhance your method as

```
public boolean compareLogin(String username, String pass) {
    String where = DB_COL_EMAIL + " = ? AND " + DB_COL_PASS + " = ?";  
    String[] whereParams = new String[]{username, pass};

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DB_NAME, columns, 
            where, 
            whereParams, 
            null, 
            null, 
                null);

    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

And yes you should read about naming convention in java or Android.

Comment: what does this " = ? AND" do ? can u please elaborate

Comment: `where` `String` has `?`s inplace of actual values and the actual values are passed in as a `String[]` and in the `whereParams` paramter. SQLite will replace those `?`s with the values from the `String[]` `whereParams`.

Comment: On more thing when I made a query without selection args, cursor.getCount() returned > 0 for email even only one result existed, but when I add selectoin args in query like you did in your answer, c.getCount() is always 0, why is that?

Comment: DB has more than 1 row but when I try to find a specific user name and password and even when it is found, cursor.getCount() is zero. I have double checked it and it is the same.

Comment: I don't no whts going on your side. But I didn't used getCount() in my solution can you check if it works

Comment: Yes it works. Well is there any other way to know if cursor is empty after making a query.

Comment: `mCursor.moveToFirst()` does the same. If cursor doesn't have any row then it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see, is that you don't close the cursor.

Do something like so:

```
Cursor c = null;
try {

    /* your stuff in here */

} finally {
    if (c != null) c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in the way you want.

```
public boolean Compare(String username, String pass) {
    Cursor c = sqlDB.query(DB_NAME, columns, DB_COL_EMAIL + "='" + username+ "'", null, null, null, null);

    // No need to check c != null and c.getCount()
    // c will not be null even if no rows returned.

    boolean found = false;
    // c.moveToFirst() will return false if no rows returned
    // so this line should be sufficient
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // while (c.moveToNext()) should be commented
        // remember you just called moveToFirst()?
        // moveToNext() will move to next row
        // and will returned false if no more rows in the cursor

        found = pass.equals(c.getString(passwordCol_number));
    }
    c.close();
    return found;
}
```